# Which devices does XCode 4.5 work with?

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, device, armv7

XCode 4.5 only allows armv7.  I'm happy with that change, as it takes less space. I'm sure some extreme assembly programmers were relieved at such a difference, making the coding more updated and streamlined.

Does anyone happen to know which devices are no longer supported?  Is it the iPhone 3G and iPod 1?

THANKS!!

Comment: iPhone 3G does not supported with Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, iPhone, iPhone 3G, and 1st gen iPod touch are definitely armv6. I believe that 2nd gen iPod touch is, too.